# I'm getting a couple errors after upgrading to Angular 14 from 13

Tags: angular14upgrade

these are the only errors I'm getting when doing ng build

```
./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??

ruleSet[1].rules[4].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??

ruleSet[1].rules[4].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

Warning: C:\documents\myapp\asupercoolapp\main\portal\client\clientapp\src\app\app.module.ts depends on 'ngx-google-places-autocomplete'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.

For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm2015/platform-server.mjs:18:0-27 - Error: 

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\documents\myapp\asupercoolapp\main\portal\client\clientapp\node_modules\@angular\platform-server\fesm2015'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.

This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
        - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "url": false }

"I don't understand this one..."

./node_modules/@angular/platform-server/fesm2015/platform-server.mjs:325:35-58 - 

Error: export 'ɵHttpInterceptorHandler' (imported as 'ɵHttpInterceptorHandler') was not found in '@angular/common/http' 
(possible exports: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpBackend, HttpClient, HttpClientJsonpModule, HttpClientModule, HttpClientXsrfModule, HttpContext, 
HttpContextToken, HttpErrorResponse, HttpEventType, HttpHandler, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, 
HttpResponseBase, HttpUrlEncodingCodec, HttpXhrBackend, HttpXsrfTokenExtractor, JsonpClientBackend, JsonpInterceptor, XhrFactory, ɵHttpInterceptingHandler)
```